# Express cos(θ/2) and sin(θ/2) in terms of cosθ

Tags: complex-analysis

Express $\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$ and $\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$ in terms of $\cos(\theta)$

My workings below
($\cos(\theta)$+ i $\sin(\theta))^\frac{1}{2}$  as $n=\frac{1}{2}$

I think the modulus equals 1 but not sure in terms of $\cos(\theta)$

Comment: That formula does't really make sense. I believe that you made a mistake. Can you write our clearly what you intended and how you were working toward it?

Comment: Have re worked question. Hope it makes more sense,

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you were trying to do and what problems you might have with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos \theta + i \sin \theta = (\cos (\theta /2) + i \sin (\theta /2))^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Equating real & imaginary parts 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos \theta  = \cos^2 (\theta /2) - \sin^2 (\theta /2) \\
 \sin \theta = 2\cos (\theta /2)  \sin (\theta /2).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: It might be helpful to give some intuition for the first equation, since there's a nice visual interpretation of why that's true.

Comment: Hi Donald, thanks for you help. Not sure why the power of n is 2 it might be some basic trig I am forgetting.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\cos \theta + i \sin \theta = e^{i \theta}= (e^{i \theta /2})^2=(\cos (\theta /2) + i \sin (\theta /2))^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity
$$\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$$
\begin{align}
\cos\theta & =\cos\left(\frac\theta 2+ \frac\theta 2\right) \\
& =\cos\left(\frac\theta 2\right)\cos\left(\frac\theta 2\right)-\sin\left(\frac\theta 2\right)\sin\left(\frac\theta 2\right)\\
\cos\theta & = \cos^2\left(\frac\theta 2\right)-\sin^2\left(\frac\theta 2\right)
\end{align}